# Error @fileswith@pti@ns

Tags: babel

So, I am having problem with this and couldn't find an answer.

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} 
\usepackage[res]
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newcent} 

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document

\begin{document}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
28
Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.28 \usepackage{
                 color}
```

I already tried everything. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Peraphs is xcolor instead of color. Missing also \end{document}.

Comment: please always post the error message _that you get from the example posted_ the error you show is from a different file, which loads color on line 28 and res on line 27 with no intervening babel.

Answer (score 2):

I have a problem of compilation with `\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res}`. I have replaced it with `article` class.  After I have removed unknown package `\usepackage{res}` and not with the bracket `[...]` or it'll give you a mistake.

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newcent} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Holy. That worked, thank you!

Comment: @Rodf No no I'm not holy :-). I am simply a very normal person who tries to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is no `res` package it would be odd to have a package and class with the same name, if you had, as you intended,

```
\usepackage{res}
```

The error would have been

```
! LaTeX Error: File `res.sty' not found.
```

but you have

```
\usepackage[res]
```

with square brackets, so this is parsed as

```
\usepackage[res]{\usepackage}
 [brazilian]{babel}
```

and latex tries to expand `\usepackage` with no arguments to get a string to use as a filename, this is doomed to failure and you get

```
! Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.
```

as some internal macro in the definition of `\usepackage` tries to find an argument but finds `}`.